# Django's cascade delete is executing the DELETE SQL twice

Tags: python, django, django-models

I've got an odd situation here, any idea why the delete SQL for the `myapp_entry_tag` table is being performed twice?

```
>>> from myapp.models import Tag
>>> from django.db import connection
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> Tag.objects.only('pk').get(pk=1).delete()
>>> pprint(connection.queries)
[{u'sql': u'SELECT `myapp_tag`.`id` FROM `myapp_tag` ''WHERE `myapp_tag`.`id` = 1 ',
  u'time': u'0.000'},
 {u'sql': u'DELETE FROM `myapp_entry_tag` WHERE `myapp_entry_tag`.`tag_id` IN (1)',
  u'time': u'0.000'},
 {u'sql': u'DELETE FROM `myapp_entry_tag` WHERE `myapp_entry_tag`.`tag_id` IN (1)',
  u'time': u'0.000'},
 {u'sql': u'DELETE FROM `myapp_tag` WHERE `id` IN (1)', u'time': u'0.000'}]
```

models.py:

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    ...

class EntryTag(models.Model):
    ...
    tag = models.ForeignKey(Tag)
```

Answer (score 0):

(sorry for answer, but I can't comment your question)

Use django-toolbar to get context of query execution. It will be probably easier to find bug.